# Add google analytics code in simple html page

Tags: html

How to add Google tracking code in simple html page I need some **code** or examples.
Or please provide some kind of proper tutorials i am new in this.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the Google App Engine? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

Comment: NO i just want simple tracking code. Thanks

Comment: Then why did you add that tag?! It looks like you've been here for a while.. did you go through the tour page? http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: OH well i removed the tag now thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Google Analytics account you will be prompted with a page with the tracking code. Just add that tracking code in the `<head>` of your html page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to GA.

Get your tracking code. Add it in the `<head>` of your html page on each page you want tracked.

```html
<head>
 <title>This Is Your Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

 <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-158081909-1"></script>
 <script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());

   gtag('config', 'UA-YOURTRACKINGCODEHERE');
 </script>
</head>
```